# Why do I get a Float data type for an Integer arithmetic function?

Tags: python

```
check = (3*3+3/3-3)
print(check)
print(type(check))
```

o/p

```
7.0
<class 'float'>
```

Logic or Fundamentals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/` operator is a float division operator. It always returns a float.

```
>>> 3/3
1.0
```

Comment: It's not a "float division operator" and it doesn't always return a float.